# path not recognized as a file in vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "C:\\MinGW\\include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"  /*Here I get this message:"Path is not a file: C:\\\\MinGW\\\\bin"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

I just started vscode setup opened folder and this is the first message i get.

Comment: The `compilerPath` should point to the [actual *compiler*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations), not just the bin folder where it is located.

Comment: @WhozCraig I changed the CompilerPath to C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0 and it still shows path is not a file but the codes are running

Comment: That's *still* a path do a directory and not to the actual compiler executable program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do I do that?

Comment: You need the path to the `gcc.exe` program.

Comment: read the VSC C/C++ doc for MinGW

Comment: Path doesn't mean directory; it means full name. If the executable file is named `gcc.exe`, the path with end with `gcc.exe` (The `.exe` can probably be omitted, though.)